# C# Replace HTML tags

Tags: c#, regex

Okay, so basically I'm creating a console application.
It scrapes values from the internet. But I need to replace the  tags,
now it shows the matches but with the tags. I have tried to replace it, but I just keep failing.

```
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(data, pattern))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
        }
```

This shows the matches, but I can't figure out how to remove the tags from there. And I can't use any match.Replace code, it just isn't working.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please post a reproduce-able problem along with sample. No one can read you mind.

Comment: Use an HTML parser such as HtmlAgilityPack rather than regex. Regex is not a good fit in general for parsing HTML. *If* your html is very simple this might work but in general it won't. And will still probably be harder than using an HTML parser.

Comment: Do you just want to remove the tags ? I can give you a fast regex for that.

Comment: Yes, I need to remove the tags.

Comment: Use my regex here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35778590/text-to-html-ratio-of-a-page-issue/35778974#35778974 It's like this `@"<(?:(?:(?:(script|style|object|embed|applet|noframes|noscript|noembed)(?:\s+(?>""[\S\s]*?""|'[\S\s]*?'|(?:(?!/>)[^>])?)+)?\s*>)[\S\s]*?</\1\s*(?=>))|(?:/?[\w:]+\s*/?)|(?:[\w:]+\s+(?:""[\S\s]*?""|'[\S\s]*?'|[^>]?)+\s*/?)|\?[\S\s]*?\?|(?:!(?:(?:DOCTYPE[\S\s]*?)|(?:\[CDATA\[[\S\s]*?\]\])|(?:--[\S\s]*?--)|(?:ATTLIST[\S\s]*?)|(?:ENTITY[\S\s]*?)|(?:ELEMENT[\S\s]*?))))>"`

Comment: I need to replace it with a ":". And I can't really understand what's on that page. I'm a beginner at C#.

Comment: On regexr I can just use "<.*?>" and that matches all the tags (the td tags), but I don't know the command to replace it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions guys, but I just found out how. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you convert Html to plain text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286813/how-do-you-convert-html-to-plain-text)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Convert-HTML-To-Plain-Text.aspx) code snippet to convert HTML to plain text:

```
// This function converts HTML code to plain text
// Any step is commented to explain it better
// You can change or remove unnecessary parts to suite your needs
public string HTMLToText(string HTMLCode)
{
 // Remove new lines since they are not visible in HTML
 HTMLCode = HTMLCode.Replace("\n", " ");

 // Remove tab spaces
 HTMLCode = HTMLCode.Replace("\t", " ");

 // Remove multiple white spaces from HTML
 HTMLCode = Regex.Replace(HTMLCode, "\\s+", " ");

 // Remove HEAD tag
 HTMLCode = Regex.Replace(HTMLCode, "<head.*?</head>", ""
                     , RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);

 // Remove any JavaScript
 HTMLCode = Regex.Replace(HTMLCode, "<script.*?</script>", ""
   , RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);

 // Replace special characters like &, <, >, " etc.
 StringBuilder sbHTML = new StringBuilder(HTMLCode);
 // Note: There are many more special characters, these are just
 // most common. You can add new characters in this arrays if needed
 string[] OldWords = {"&nbsp;", "&amp;", "&quot;", "&lt;", 
   "&gt;", "&reg;", "&copy;", "&bull;", "&trade;"};
 string[] NewWords = {" ", "&", "\"", "<", ">", "Â®", "Â©", "â€¢", "â„¢"};
 for(int i = 0; i < OldWords.Length; i++)
 {
   sbHTML.Replace(OldWords[i], NewWords[i]);
 }

 // Check if there are line breaks (<br>) or paragraph (<p>)
 sbHTML.Replace("<br>", "\n<br>");
 sbHTML.Replace("<br ", "\n<br ");
 sbHTML.Replace("<p ", "\n<p ");

 // Finally, remove all HTML tags and return plain text
 return System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(
   sbHTML.ToString(), "<[^>]*>", "");
}
```

Or use the [HtmlAgilityPack](http://html-agility-pack.net/) - which you should use anyway if you scrape with .NET: